# Change nix-build's TMPDIR from shell.nix

Tags: temporary-files, nix, nix-shell

I'm trying to use `nix-shell` with a `shell.nix` file to get a clean development environment but I don't know how to change the location of the temporary build directories.

The `buildInputs` packages are built in `/tmp` but this path doesn't have enough space and I get an `error: [Errno 28] No space left on device` during the build.

I tried running `nix-shell` with a modified `TMPDIR` environment variable but it only affects the location of the `nix-shell` temporary files. The `nix-build` files are still put in `/tmp`.

I also tried to export a new value for `TMPDIR` in the `shellHook` but it doesn't work.

How can I change the `TMPDIR` of `nix-build` when it's started by `nix-shell`?

Here's my `shell.nix`:

```hs
let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
in
  pkgs.mkShell {
    name = "something";
    buildInputs = with pkgs; [
      python38
      python38Packages.pytorchWithCuda
    ];

    shellHook = ''
    '';
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer [on the NixOS forum](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/changing-nix-builds-tmpdir-from-shell-nix/20264/2):

> If this is a mutli-user install, you need to modify the Nix daemon’s TMPDIR.

To do that on my system I created a `/etc/systemd/system/nix-daemon.service.d/override.conf` with:

```
[Service]
Environment=TMPDIR=/var/tmp/nix-daemon
```

Comment: On NixOS, you'd do `systemd.services.nix-daemon.environment.TMPDIR = "/var/tmp/nix-daemon";`

Comment: Didn't work for me.  Not sure why.